# pfSense iso.gz doesn't seem to be a compressed iso image

Tags: iso-image, 7-zip, gzip

I downloaded the latest pfSense ISO (pfSense-2.0.1-RELEASE-i386.iso.gz) and had 7zip extract it, but it just shows me the disk contents.  I cannot extract the actual ISO file to burn it with the boot sector properly in place.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

7zip is most likely gunzipping the compressed file, and then opening the iso for you.

The best bet is to gunzip the file with `gunzip`:

```
$ gunzip pfSense-2.0.1-RELEASE-i386.iso.gz
```

This should result in a file called `pfSense-2.0.1-RELEASE-i386.iso` that is the iso itself.